# My add to cart function is replacing items in the cart instead of adding

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array that stores objects of products, I store the product details in session storage and then get the details and use those parameters for my add to cart function but instead of adding items it replaces the last item in the array with the new one.

If i call the add to cart function in isolation and give it parameters it works fine but once i call it from another function it does not add but replaces items in the cart

This is my add to cart function

```
//add item to cart
function addToCart(name, type, price, size, count){

    for(var i in cart){
        if(cart[i].name === name){
            cart[i].count += count;
            return;
        }
    }
        var product = new Product(name, type, price, size, count);
        cart.push(product);
        saveCart();
}
```

And the function that calls add to Cart

```
//set up for add to cart function
function cartSetUp(){

    var name = sessionStorage.getItem("product name");
    var price = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("product price"));
    var type = sessionStorage.getItem("product type");
    var image = sessionStorage.getItem("product image");
    var count = $("#product-quantity").val();
    var size = $('input[name=size]:checked').val();


    addToCart(name, type, price, size, count)

}
```

Comment: What is `saveCart()`?  When you step through the code in your debugger, where specifically does the problem occur?

Comment: you should take the cart obj from session and passs into add cart function, then only it will able to append existing cart

Comment: @David save cart() saves the cart in local storage

Comment: ```function saveCart(){
    localStorage.setItem("shopping cart", JSON.stringify(cart));
}```

Comment: I believe problem is in a code you didn't provide. Try adding `console.log(cart)` before `cart.push(product)` command and also immediately after you loaded cart from the localStorage. I suspect, you are losing the last item in your cart sometimes between loading cart from the localStorage and appending new product there